# Qt 5.2.1 | Невозможно запустить qmake

Tags: qt, qmake

Решил ознакомиться с Qt и сразу столкнулся с проблемой при компиляции
[image: Ошибка при компиляции]

На форумах советуют разве что проверить корректность путей к файлам, и наличие кириллических символов в них - пути проверил, все в порядке.
Кто как решил данную проблему - поделитесь.
P.S. в реестре есть пустой ключ без путей, так задумано?

================================

Проблему решил

- Поправил Path в переменных среды - указал путь до mingw48_32\bin
- Отключил теневую сборку, которая была включена по умолчанию

[image: Теневая сборка]

Comment: я бы для начала проверил, есть по указанному пути qmake.exe. И в любом случае - 5.2 - это немного древнее. и mingw до более свежего.